# Wrong read from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am uploading a product to Firebase using this code :

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("ProductsImages").child(product.UniqueID()).child("MainImage.png")
            if let mainChosenImage = self.selectedImageToUpload
            {
                if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mainChosenImage, 0.2)
                {
                    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil)
                    {
                        (StorageMetaData, error) in
                        if error != nil
                        {
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }

                        self.mainImageURL = StorageMetaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        if let urlString = self.mainImageURL
                        {
                            self.ref.child("Products").child(product.UniqueID()).child("MainImage").setValue(urlString)
                            self.ref.child("Users").child(user.uid).child("Products").child(product.UniqueID()).child("MainImage").setValue(urlString)
                            product.AddImageURLToProduct(URL: urlString)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            product.RegisterProductForAllUsers(database: self.ref)
            product.RegisterProductForAddingUser(database: self.ref)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMyProductsViewController", sender: self)
```

Now I know that writing an image like this is async (1), but after item is added (Let's say we ignore picture for now), I have this in Firebase:

[saved Firebase Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMWNR.jpg)

But when I go back to my collectionView and load the information (It happens in the ViewDidLoad method), this is the information I read:

[Product information read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IyYX.jpg)

This is my code for ViewDidLoad:

```
if let currentUserID = loggedOnUserID
    {
        // Retrieve the products and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("Products").observe(.childAdded, with:
            { (snapshot) in

                // Code to execute when new product is added
                let prodValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let prodName = prodValue?["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                let prodPrice = prodValue?["Price"] as? Double ?? -1
                let prodDesc = prodValue?["Description"] as? String ?? ""
                let prodURLS = prodValue?["MainImage"] as? String ?? ""
                let prodAmount = prodValue?["Amount"] as? Int ?? 0
                let prodID = snapshot.key

                let prodToAddToView = Product(name: prodName, price: prodPrice, currency: "NIS", description: prodDesc, location: "IL",
                                              toSell: false, toBuy: false, owner: currentUserID, uniqueID: prodID, amount: prodAmount)

                if (prodURLS != "")
                {
                    prodToAddToView.AddImageURLToProduct(URL: prodURLS)
                }

                self.products.append(prodToAddToView)
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.MyProductsCollection.reloadData()
                }
            }
        ) // Closes observe function
```

Also - my code writing to Database :

```
public func RegisterProductForAllUsers(database dataBase: DatabaseReference)
{
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Name").setValue(self.Name())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("UniqueID").setValue(self.UniqueID())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Price").setValue(self.Price())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Description").setValue(self.Description())
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToBuy?").setValue(self.m_ToBuy)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("ToSell?").setValue(self.m_ToSell)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Owner").setValue(self.m_Owner)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("Amount").setValue(self.m_Amount)
    dataBase.child("Products").child(self.UniqueID()).child("MainImage").setValue(self.m_PicturesURLs.first)
}
```

I am writing "Name" first, which is maybe the reason I only read name properly? Is there a way to make all these writings be atomic ?

with only 1 value for some reason. (2)
1) Any way to make it sync ?
2) How can I read the proper values ?